# useEffect(): Howto refactor componetDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I have defined a state:

```html
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
```

which in my class component I updated as follows:

```html
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.cartItem.quantity !== prevProps.cartItem.quantity) {
            let quantity = this.props.cartItem.quantity;
            this.setState((state, props) => {
                return {
                    quantity
                }}
            );
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState((state, props) => {
            return {
                quantity: props.cartItem.quantity
            }}
        );       
    }
```

The componentDidMount aspect I achieve by doing:

```html
    useEffect(() => {
      setQuantity(parseInt(props.cartItem.quantity));
    });
```

How do I achieve the same componentDidUpdate() functionality using `useEffect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a "dependency" to your useEffect hook.

```
const { cartItem } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  setQuantity(parseInt(cartItem.quantity));
}, [cartItem]);
```

This means, whenever the `cartItem` prop changes, it will trigger an update your state, including on component mount.